# Getting angular route to trigger event to trigger on navigation to current url

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

Using angulars $route

(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

An event is emited when a route starts, ends and so forth. My use case is that whenever a user clicks a `a href` I want to call some method.

However when the user is located at say `/user/settings"` and clicks on a `href` linking to the same path `/user/settings` no event is emitted.

I don't want to add `ng-click` on every a `href` in my application but I need to have my method triggering, always when a user clicks a `href`.

Any suggestions would be welcome

kind regards

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you just want an event listener instead of monitoring the route? I would just make a directive that listens for that click, instead of using ng-click. Is there any reason this wouldn't work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's a good idea and I will investigare that. To clearify my usercase the route itself is not important as you mentioned, its just that I want a single place where, whenever the user performs an action (it's hrefs at the moment, but might as well be buttons, divs, or something else), If that actions is a redirect to another page or to the same page (which in my app means, change content) I want my navigation menu to toggle since they clicked something and want to se the result rather than the menu iteself